# Angularjs 1.0 empty an array methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to empty an array using angularjs
I used following but it will take empty array and UI
Following are working but taking much time to empty an array

```
$scope.abc=[];
$scope.abc.length=0;
```

Any other method is there to empty an array quickly for large data.

Comment: `$scope.abc = [];` should be all to empty the array. How do mean it takes much time to empty the array? Perhaps digest doesn't happen as fast. You can try calling `$scope.$digest()` when you empty the array.

Comment: Problem is most likely from code not shown

Comment: As suggested by @Oluwafemi Sule you can call $digest to get the changes refelected immediately but if you are getting error "digest is already running " on calling $digest you can try $apply or $applyAsync.